# How to scroll down <sphere> with the help of react-three-drei (Scroll-controls)

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want my sphere bubble to be in center of my screen even if we scroll pages.
is there any way toh do this

here is sandbox of it

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-paper-cvl4fy?file=/src/App.js

I searched serveral things but didnt found anything

Answer (score 0):

Just take the Circular component out of the Scroll Wrapper and it should work!
Your code should be something like this

```
<ScrollControls pages={3}>
    <Scroll HTML>
        <Html />
    </Scroll>
    <Circularr />
</ScrollControls>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).